# C# Extracting from an Email header using a Regex

Tags: c#, regex

So im trying to extract different parts from an email header in C#. I think im just hopeless with Regex.

I have the following:

`[["X-Mailgun-Incoming", "Yes"], ["X-Envelope-From", "<dwdwdw@dwdwdw.com>"],["Thread-Topic", "What is status"]]`

Using a regex I want say the Thread-Topic

I am trying:

`[\"(Thread)\-(Topic)\", (\")?:[A-Z][a-z][a-z]+(\")]`

Ideally Id like to just change the words to extract some of the other parameters

Comment: How are you getting that format? Do you have access to the raw email? If so, it'd be far easier and less error prone to use an email handling library to extract the information.

Comment: Thanks mate. But we are building an email parser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get raw string

```
var str = "[[\"X-Mailgun-Incoming\",\"Yes\"],[\"X-Envelope-From\",\"<dwdwdw@dwdwdw.com>\"],[\"Thread-Topic\",\"What is status\"]]";
var arr = str.Split(new string[] { "],[", "[[", "]]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var kpv = arr.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry but I need a regex

Comment: You should say so in the question

Answer (score 0):

If regex i would do something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParseHeadersToDictionary_MultipleHeaders_HeadersAreParsed()
{
    var emailHeaders = "[[\"X-Mailgun-Incoming\",\"Yes\"],[\"X-Envelope-From\",\"<dwdwdw@dwdwdw.com>\"],[\"Thread-Topic\",\"What is status\"]]";

    var regex = new Regex(@"\[""(?<key>.*?)"",\s?""(?<value>.*?)""]");
    Dictionary<string,string> headers = regex.Matches(emailHeaders).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(item => item.Groups["key"].Value, item => item.Groups["value"].Value);

    var result = headers["Thread-Topic"];

    Assert.AreEqual("What is status", result);
}
```